# How can I Install a theme from Github

Tags: themes

I saw this theme around the web and i liked it a lot.
https://github.com/baurigae/polar-night
But i'm a newbie on Ubuntu/Linux, and i have no idea how to install it. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the Github page and click the Download ZIP button.
2. Extract the downloaded archive and rename the directory 'polar-night'
3. Move the whole directory to ...

**Edit**: some more informations.
Two things you should know about themes:

1-You can move them to more than one place: `/usr/share/themes` make them available to all users, but you must have administration privileges to do so. There are two other places in your home folder: `.local/share/themes` and `.themes`.

2-If you open the theme folder, you'll notice it contains some sub-folders named after the window manager you're using. In other words, if the theme don't have any folder 'Unity' for instance, you will not be able to use it with Unity.

**Now, if you want to move the extracted folder to your home configuration**:

- Open a 'Files' window (Nautilus), and display your home folder.
- Hit `ctrl-H`: this will show you the hidden files, and particularly the folders .themes and .local which are most often hidden.
- If you choose to put the theme into `.local/share/themes` you may have to create the folder.
- Go to your '`Download`' folder, and move the theme into the chosen folder (cut/paste, drag & drop, etc...).

**If you want to put it into /usr/share/themes**

Using Nautilus will fail because you've not the write permission on this folder. So, hit `ctrl-Alt-T` to open a terminal window.

- In this window, type `sudo mv` (don't forget the space after mv).
- Select the theme folder in Nautilus and drag it to the terminal window. It will write the folder path for you.
- Hit space one more time
- Select the `/usr/share/themes` folder in Nautilus and drag it to the terminal window (or just type: /usr/share/themes)
- Hit return, the terminal will ask for your password. Enter it and hit return. You're done.

HTH

Comment: Please explain your answer more and give clear instaructions - newbie on Ubuntu/Linux remember. Something like `You'll probably have to do this in a terminal using sudo mv ...` is not so newbie friendly.

Comment: @Pyrophorus I would use `~/.local/share/themes`. No need to use `/usr/share/themes` if it's a single-user system.

Comment: @Glutanimate: you're right, of course... if it's a single user system... :-)

Comment: @Pyphorus Thnak you!!! It helped me a lot. I have no ideia it was that simple. Thank you for your help.